DAX expression to get previous years averages
I am having a problem to calculate previous years averages of a column
I have tried below DAX:
Average_Prev_Three_Years_DA_Per_Date-2 = 
VAR PresentYear = YEAR(TODAY())
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(
            ALL('Summary Table'),
            YEAR('Summary Table'[Date]) = PresentYear
        ),
        "Avg_Prev_Three_Years_DA",
        CALCULATE(
            AVERAGE('Summary Table'[Daily Adjustment]),
            FILTER(
                ALL('Summary Table'),
                YEAR('Summary Table'[Date]) >= PresentYear - 3 && YEAR('Summary Table'[Date]) < PresentYear
                    && MONTH('Summary Table'[Date]) = MONTH('Summary Table'[Date])
                    && DAY('Summary Table'[Date]) = DAY('Summary Table'[Date])
                    && 'Summary Table'[Date] = EARLIER('Summary Table'[Date])
            )
        )
    )


I would suggest you to create a new measure named Total Daily Adjustments which will be calculated like this:
Total Daily Adjustments = 
AVERAGEX(
    'Summary Table',
    'Summary Table'[Daily Adjustment]
)

and then you will create another measure named Previous Year Daily Adjustment
Previous Year Daily Adjustment= 
CALCULATE(
    [Total Daily Adjustments],
    DATEADD(
        'Summary Table'[Date],
        -1,
        YEAR
    )
)

and instead of -1 you can write the number of years that you want to look for

I need average of previous years

The same way you calculate Average of Daily Adjustments, you can use it to calculate last year's Total Daily Adjustments =  AVERAGEX(     'Summary Table',     'Summary Table'[Previous Year Daily Adjustment] )
